# Morphisms of algebras

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let's put : $ j = e^{i \dfrac{2 \pi}{3}} $, $ J = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & j & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & j^2 \end{pmatrix} $ and : $ \mathrm{Circ}_3 ( \mathbb{C} ) $ is the set of all $ 3 \times  3 $ circulant matrices over $ \mathbb{C} $.
I would like to find some morphisms of algebras over $ \mathbb{C} $ : $ \Phi : \mathrm{Circ}_3 ( \mathbb{C} ) \to \mathrm{Circ}_3 ( \mathbb{C} ) $ defined by the equivalence relation $ \sim $ such that :
$ \forall C , C' \in \mathrm{Circ}_3 ( \mathbb{C} ) $ : $ \ \  C \sim C' \ \ \ \Longleftrightarrow \ \ \ \Phi ( C ) = \Phi ( C' ) $, which respect the following condition :
$ \forall C \in \mathrm{Circ}_3 ( \mathbb{C} ) $ : $ \ \ C \ \sim \ J^{-1} C J \ \sim \ JCJ^{-1}  $.
Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I found this map : $ \Phi \Big( \begin{pmatrix}  a & b & c \\ c & a & b \\ b & c & a \end{pmatrix} \Big) = \begin{pmatrix} a^3 & b^3 & c^3 \\ c^3 & a^3 & b^3 \\ b^3 & c^3 & a^3 \end{pmatrix} $, but, unfortunately, it's not a morphism of algebras over $ \mathbb{C} $. Can someone help me please ? Thanks a lot.